# how to debug when flask blocking

Tags: python, debugging, flask

I was running flask in a public_ip server(with some users)
run command is

`(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)`

but flask server blocking somewhere one hour ago  (the log show last request is one hour before)
so how can I debug on it?(figure out it's blocking on which python line?)
I have tried

`gdb python3.4-dbg pid`,but my flask app can't run by python3.4-dbg,for

```
 from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command is:

```
gdb -p pid
```

to attach to a running process.

Answer (score 1):

oh,I find a way
after install python-dbg
use gdb python pid to attach flask
and use py-bt py-list py-locals to check the blocking stack